# Using Line Search Method for Constrained Optimization

Tags: constrained-optimization, nonlinear-programming

Suppose we have a $f(x)$ to be minimized (we only know that $f(x)$ is three-differentiable), and a feasible, convex set of $S$ such that all $x$ belong to $S$. Using line search method, how we can "mathematically" prove that a descending direction pointing from previous $x$ towards a new $x$ within the $S$ exists?

And, how we can find the best $a\geq 0$ such that $x + ad$ belongs to $S$? I mean if we have a direction, how can we optimize the $d$ to have the least iterations?

1.I'm neither a beginner nor an expert, somewhere in between.
2.I need all the iterates to be feasible.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! It would help if you told us how much you already know about constrained optimization (please don't add a comment but edit your question). It's also important to know whether you need that all the iterates $x$ are feasible, or whether it's enough that the limit of the iteration is. (Most methods for constrained optimization work for the former situation; for the latter, you could look at Zoutendijk's methods.)

Comment: And to your first point: If there is no such direction, pretty much by definition $x$ is already a minimizer and you're done. (Provided the boundary of $S$ is not too nasty.)

Comment: Is $S$ a convex set?  What about $f(x)$?

Comment: yes, $S$ is convex and $f(x)$ is 3-differentiable